# Responsive solution for long URLs (that exceed the device width)

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

As the title implies, while building responsive sites, I often run into an issue with long(ish) URLs breaking my fluid grid and causing horizontal scrolling on smaller devices. Because they're one long string, they don't wrap and push the width of their container to wider than the device width...

```
 <--device-->
______________
|             |
| http://longurlthatdoesntfit.com
|             |
|             |
```

Sometimes I make the container `overflow:hidden` but that just chops off the end of the URL and it tends to lock glitchy. Another approach might be to shrink the font-size on smaller devices, but in situations where the URL lengths vary, it would mean shrinking it WAY down to ensure it always has enough space.

There must be a better way.

Comment: I presume there's a good reason why you need to display the **entire** URL, rather that just hiding it behind some shorter link text, or even a truncated version of the URL.

Comment: @jcsanyi In the relevant situations, I'm usually showing the user a URL so they can distribute it. Think: YouTube video link or something similar. So the actual URL is kind of important in case they select/copy it rather than right clicking it. However, the truncation is a good idea. I was thinking of something like: `mydomain.com/begin...end/123456` so at least the unique part of the URL would show.

Answer (score 15):

If neither hiding or scrolling overflow work for you, consider forcefully [word wrapping in CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp):

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to add word-wrap: break-word; to your grid style.

```
<div style="word-wrap: break-word;">
  <a href="#">http://www.extraverylongurlthatdoesntfit.com</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution `word-wrap: break-word` did the trick only after I added a `max-width` to the anchor tag. Specific to my design:

```
a {word-wrap: break-word; max-width:300px;}
```

Comment: Because your `<a>` tag is being displayed as block or inline-block.